# Tab key not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a key with value=tab when clicking on tab it changes the focus to next textbox its fine up till here but suppose i focus on second textbox and then press 1 key from the keypad made in webpage.after that if i press the tab key again it focus on first textbox whereas it should focus on third textbox.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/11/)

```
$txt[0].setSelectionRange(pos+1, pos+1);



});  


$('.delete').on('click',function() {

    var $myInput = $txt;
    $myInput.val($myInput.val().slice(0, -1));
});

$('.clear').on('click',function() {
    $txt.val('');
});
```

Comment: fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just right:

```
$txt.focus();
```

inside:

```
$(".num").on("click", function(e) {
    if (! $txt) return false; // If tracker is cleared, just return

    var prev = $txt.val();
    var num = this.value;
    var pos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
    var newValue = prev.substring(0, pos) + num + prev.substring(pos);
    $txt.val(newValue);
    $txt[0].setSelectionRange(pos+1, pos+1);


        $txt.focus();



});
```

You will get the correct focus.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/t4ce2jtu/12/) here.

Comment: thanks mate one more thing why is my tab button not seems to be pressing as other buttons(it seems to be disable as in style why?)

Comment: what if i remove it.will it make any difference?

Comment: its not working can you help me. i want it to be same as other buttons else it is looking odd in my webpage